# How to connect database using system dsn in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created system dsn using mysql driver now i have connection path. how to use it in java code.to get connection.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ODBC. Use MySql JDBC [Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Take a look at [Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Tutorial link:

1. [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)
2. [Writing JDBC Applications with MySQL](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html)
3. [Using JDBC with MySQL, Getting Started](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381)

Comment: Give some examples for connection.

Comment: In c# it is easy.but in java i don't know how to use

Comment: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TOY2","root","root");can i give different dsn path here.